# Write a Haskell program insert x n k lt that inserts x n times after the particular kth element of the list lt

Tags: haskell

Write a Haskell program insert x n k lt that inserts x n times after the particular kth element of the list lt.
for example:-
insert 1 2 3 [1,2,3,4] = [1,2,3,1,1,4]

Here I tried doing by many way but couldn't get the exact way to solve. Can somebody help me with this??

Comment: show what you've tried and how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you some hints.

The thing you're making has three parts: the first bit of the original list, the new section in the middle, and the rest of the original list, so look on [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) for

```
 splitAt
```

and

```
replicate
```

and think about how you could combine things back together.